# Stop my website from defaulting to Times New Roman for a pre full render font

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'helvetica_ce_35_thinregular';
    src: 
         url('Font/helvetica_neue_ce_35_thin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('Font/helvetica_neue_ce_35_thin-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: "helvetica_ce_35_thinregular", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #242529;
}
```

Ok so I'm trying to load Helvetica, whilst my custom font downloads so it doesn't show up as the yucky Times New Roman loading font.

I've tried with and with out `font-display` as well as `font-display:` `swap` and `fallback` and still no luck!

Additionally I've used:
`<link rel="preload" as="font" href="path/to/font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: Remove `, Helvetica`

Comment: It should still show up as Helvetica, but maybe just add some more fallbacks (arial is usually a good, universally available bet). Otherwise, you could load it through window.fonts and then display the page, or wait for window.load, which should include _all_ assets loaded before displaying the page.

Comment: 1. Removing ```, Helvetica``` hasn't helped.
2. Adding ```, Ariel``` hasn't helped either :/

re: Using ```window.fonts``` I'm trying to use as little JS as possible!